# Left margin is appearing in html that I don't want

Tags: html, css, margin

There is an extra left margin in this nav bar that I am unable to change fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ucp2o79b/)

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>

                    <a class="navlic" href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a class="navli" href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                    <a class="navli" href="blog.html"><li>Blog</li></a>
                    <a class="navli" href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <span><h1></h1></span>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p></p>

        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS is in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucp2o79b/)

Comment: Technically that is not `margin` of `.nav` but `padding` of `.nav`. Because you have your navigation should be fixed position so positioning using `left` will not affected efficiently to `ul` inside it. Check my code. Hope that's all you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nav` object has a fixed position...use `left:0` instead

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ucp2o79b/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It's `padding` not `margin`

```
.nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this at the start of css. not sure u remove default padding & margin yet but this works fine in fiddle

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code:

`.nav ul li,a{
    float:left;
}`

Hope it'll work. for make it more beautiful add `margin-right` to make a space between your menu. Just like this

`.nav ul li,a{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pguyLqb9/)